# How to add authentication to mongodb 2.6?

Tags: mongodb

I have existing a test server running mongodb 2.6 on ubuntu. Same version is running on my macbook. In both machines, I upgraded from mongodb 2.4 using standard upgrade mechanisms. Now I need to set up username and password based authentication

On my mac, I updated mongodb to 2.6 using brew update. I

I tried the following command on my Mac

```
$mongo
>db.getSiblingDatabase('admin')
>db.createUser({user:"root", pwd:"mycomplexpassword", roles:[ "userAdminAnyDatabase", "readWrite" ] } )
```

I got the following error

```
Error: couldn't add user: User and role management commands require auth data to have schema version 3 but found 1 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1004
```

Hence I am unable enable auth to mongodb. How to solve the issue? Googling for the error does not seem to return anything useful right now.

PS: Should I expect the same issue to appear when I add authentication to mongodb on my servers?

Comment: Come on man! Which idiot wants this to be closed now? What is wrong with this question?

Comment: Same happened with my previous question as well. I am asking a very specific question, aren't I?

Comment: you can see mongodb issue ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12893

Comment: I did see this, but could not understand how to fix my issue with the information there.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The schema of `db.system.users` in mongodb 2.4 and 2.6 are different which caused you fail to create new user.

2.4 schema

```
db.system.users.find()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53675bc48ff842a0657e25ff"),
    "user" : "root",
    "pwd" : "c2ff9601c8590812f0d40b9f60869679",
    "roles" : [
        "userAdminAnyDatabase",
        "readWrite"
    ]
}
```

2.6 schema

```
db.system.users.find()
{
    "_id" : "admin.root",
    "user" : "root",
    "db" : "admin",
    "credentials" : {
        "MONGODB-CR" : "c2ff9601c8590812f0d40b9f60869679"
    },
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

<strike>I did not find an official way to convert them.
So, you may need to convert 2.4 data in `db.system.users` to 2.6 format manually, or drop all old users in 2.4 and recreate them in 2.6.</strike>

You can use the following command to upgrade.

`db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 });`

References:

1. [Upgrade User Authorization Data to 2.6 Format](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade-authorization/#run-authschemaupgrade-command)
2. [Sobolev Eugene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23523633/2349721)

Comment: How do I drop all the users?

Comment: switching database to admin `use admin`, and removing all users  `db.system.users.remove({})`

Answer (score 24):

Try this command in mongo console

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 });
```

[Upgrade authorization schema.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade-authorization/#upgrade-authorization-schema)

Comment: This looks like a better answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the above answers are correct but what made it work for me were the followings steps (F.Y.I, I am on version 2.6.8):

1.Run in  mongo:

```
db.system.version.update({}, {$set: {currentVersion: 3}});
```

2.Run in  mongo:

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 });
```

3.Run in  mongo:

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: “your_user_name”,
    pwd: “your_password”,
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db:"admin" } ]
  }
)
```

4. Add the following to /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

   `auth=true`
5. restart mongo:

   `mongod --dbpath /data/db`
6. Go to shell on Mac and login (also notice the single quotations around user name and password):

   `mongo admin -u 'your_use_name' -p 'your_password'`

Answer (score 0):

My mongoDb version 2.6.5
Issue below command

`db.system.version.update({}, {$set: {currentVersion: 3}});`

Comment: This command didn't work for me, but `db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 });` did.